# How scroll infinite in left right both direction using pageView builder in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

At the first time of app opening user will see a pageview.
In pageview builder initial value starts from the 0. At first time page opening user will see page index 0.

```
PageView.builder(
   controller: pageController,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return MyPage(data: dataList[index]);
});
```

If pagecount is not provided then, user can able to swipe right direction infinitely, but not left side.

I want that, user can swipe left right in both direction infinitely. User will page index of 0. Then user can not swipe at left direction. So i want to make this happen.

i.e. user can swipe a -1 , -2 index like that..

How to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t really under stand the use-case, but You can do this by setting up your own page controller

```
PageController pageController = PageController(
  initialPage: 0,
  viewportFraction: 1.0,
);

// Function to move to the next page
void nextPage() {
  pageController.animateToPage(
    pageController.page.toInt() + 1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeIn,
  );
}

// Function to move to the previous page
void previousPage() {
  pageController.animateToPage(
    pageController.page.toInt() - 1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
  );
}

// Logic to make sure the page index never goes out of bounds
// This will make sure that the user can swipe infinitely
pageController.addListener(() {
  if (pageController.page.toInt() >= dataList.length - 1) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      0,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  } else if (pageController.page.toInt() <= 0) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      dataList.length - 1,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }
});

PageView.builder(
   controller: pageController,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
   return MyPage(data: dataList[index]);
});
```

This way, the user can swipe left and right infinitely without ever going out of bounds. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it my code is work perfectly

at first declare a member variable for the current page index

```
int page_index=0;
int page_index=/*your list length*/

PageController controller; 
bool _isReverse = false; //for controlling the directions 
@override
initState(){
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
       controller=PageController(initialPage: page_index);
    });
    super.initState();
      }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    child:NotificationListener<UserScrollNotification>(
    onNotification: (notification) {
        final ScrollDirection direction = notification.direction;
        setState(() {
            if(_isReverse && page_index==0 ){
                if(direction.name=="forward"){
                    _isReverse=false;
                }
            }else{
                if(page_index==0)
                    if(direction.name=="forward"){
                        _isReverse=true;
                    }
            }
        });
        return true;
      },
    child: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        reverse: _isReverse,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
                page_index=index;
            });
        },
    physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    controller: controller,
   
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Text((index%itemsNumber).toString());
}),));}
```